# Редактирования изображения node.js для бота Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord-api

Вобщем, у меня есть бот на Discord, мне нужно что бы при заходе в группу этот бот кидал картинку(с зарание подготовленым фоном) с ником человека(+- по центру). Можно ли как то реализовать редактирования картинки для вставки текста в неё?

Answer (score -1):

Jimp в помощь https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp

```
new Jimp(256, 256, '#FFFFFF', (err, image) => {
  // Создает изображение 256x256 с белой заливкой
  Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_16_BLACK).then(function (font) {
    image.print(
      font, 
      0, // x
      0, // y
      {
        text: 'Hello world!',
        alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
        alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
      }),
      256, // max width
      256 // max height
    );
    image.write("/path/to/save")
  })
});
```

Либо, если изображение уже есть:

```
Jimp.read('/path/to/img', (err, image) => {
  // дальше так же
});
```